# Polyfill or Ponyfill regex(lookahead, lookbehind, name group) for old browser

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently I have a use case where I need to grab the first path after **'/#/'** in url until **'/'**

```
// lookbehind and lookahead
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/#/ask/anything-here'
    .match(/(?<=\/#\/).+(?=\/)/)
// ["ask" ...] I get word 'ask' in this case.

// supported in old browser
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/#/ask/anything-here'
    .match(/\/#\/(.+)\//)
// ["/#/ask/", "ask", ...] I can get word 'ask' in res[1]
```

Im using positive lookbehind and positive lookahead here but as soon as I run unit test in CI/CD, it error because we are still using old browser version(Chrome 56) while my machine is using Chrome 76.

In caniuse website https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind, Chrome start to support lookahead and lookbehind on version 62.

So my question is, it is possible to polyfill or ponyfill **lookahead, lookbehind and name groups** regex to old browsers.

Comment: `#\/([^\/]+)\/` How about this ?

Comment: Do you even need to use a regular expression here? a couple of `split` calls would get you the word 'ask': `('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/#/ask/anything-here'.split('#', 2)[1]||'').split('/', 2)[1]`

Comment: If you wanted truly to polyfill, you'd need to modify [`RegExp.prototype[Symbol.match]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/@@match), which I don't recommend.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I don't think a polyfill would be possible - regex literal syntax is not parsed via a modifiable function, right? In which case, the plain regex expression (before being passed to `.match`) would throw a `SyntaxError` while it's being parsed

Comment: @CertainPerformance that is true, yes. So hypothetically, a babel plugin that transforms regex literals with lookbehinds into a custom object with a `Symbol.match` method would be possible, but a polyfill would not.

Comment: @DeanTaylor, ya sure we have a lot of option to solve this. But I was asking is it possible to polyfill/ponyfill lookbehind, lookahead, and name groups for regex.

Comment: Years later, you can use a [Babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-named-capturing-groups-regex) to make named capture groups work, but apparently not lookaheads and lookbehinds.

Answer (score -2):

Why not simply use [`URL API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and select [`hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/hash) then remove `#/` from statrting

```js
let url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/#/ask/anything-here'


let valueAfterHash = (url)=>{
  let parsed = new URL(url)
  return parsed.hash.replace(/^#\//,'')
}


console.log(valueAfterHash(url))
console.log(valueAfterHash(`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/anything-here`))
```

If you want to use perl falvour of regex, you can use [`xregexp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xregexp) library which supports a lot of functions which is not natively present in JS regex