# Lookbehind regex not working for Safari and some firefox browsers

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the below code for detecting the usage of operators along with non-english characters.

```
/**
 * Prepares a unicode aware RegEx pattern for operators
 *
 * \b (word boundary - wb) can be written as (?:(?<=^)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?=$)|(?<=\W)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?=\W))
 * \B (non-word boundary - nwb) can be written as (?:(?<=^)(?=\W)|(?<=\W)(?=$)|(?<=\W)(?=\W)|(?<=\w)(?=\w))
 * Unicode-aware \w pattern is [\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]
 *
 */

const w = String.raw`[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]`;
const nw = String.raw`[^\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]`;
const uwb = String.raw`(?:(?<=^)(?=${w})|(?<=${w})(?=$)|(?<=${nw})(?=${w})|(?<=${w})(?=${nw}))`;
const unwb = String.raw`(?:(?<=^)(?=${nw})|(?<=${nw})(?=$)|(?<=${nw})(?=${nw})|(?<=${w})(?=${w}))`;

const OPERATOR_REGEX = new RegExp(
  String.raw`(?!${unwb}"[^"“”]*)${uwb}(and|or|not|exclude)(?=.*\s)${uwb}(?![^"“”]*"${unwb})`,
  'giu'
);

const query1 = '(Java or "化粧" or 化粧品)';
const query2 = '(Java or 化粧 or 化粧品)';

console.log(query1.split(OPERATOR_REGEX));
console.log(query2.split(OPERATOR_REGEX));
```

This is a impressive approach [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74611855/unicode-flag-not-working-for-regex-in-javascript) but Safari browser doesn't support lookbehind regex patterns [(Lookbehind in JS regular expressions)](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind).

What can be a good approach to make this logic work for Safari browser?

Answer (score 0):

[Lookbehind was shipped in Firefox 78](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/78#javascript), and looks like it's being [implemented right now in WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=174931).

Also see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57263289/polyfill-or-ponyfill-regexlookahead-lookbehind-name-group-for-old-browser), where the responses say it's not possible to polyfill.